# BenQ RP7502 won't update Apps

Tags: updates, firewall, smart-tv

We are using BenQ Interactive Flat Panels (IFPs) at school, and we are having issues with updating the apps.

The firewall rules we have set up *should* bypass all authentication, but when it comes to updating the apps, the download either just hangs (i.e. when using DMS) or immediately fails (when attempting a download on the device).

System version updates work without issue, but a reset will not "download" the system version, this must be run off a USB instead.

We have reserved the DHCP IPs (both Wifi and Eth) and assigned them to the firewall rules listed below (provided by BenQ):

| App | URL/DNS |
| --- | --- |
| EZWrite | https://ezwriteupload-eu.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ https://ezwriteupload.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com https://ezwrite.benq.com/ https://ezwrite-relay.benq.com/ https://service-portal.benq.com https://iam.benq.com *.pubnub.com *.pndsn.com *.pubnub.net *.pubnub.io stun.l.google.com stun1.l.google.com stun2.l.google.com stun3.l.google.com stun4.l.google.com stun.services.mozilla.com 23.21.150.121 stun01.sipphone.com stun.ekiga.net stun.fwdnet.net stun.ideasip.com stun.iptel.org stun.rixtelecom.se stun.schlund.de stunserver.org stun.softjoys.com stun.voiparound.com stun.voipbuster.com stun.voipstunt.com stun.voxgratia.org stun.xten.com |
| EZWrite OTA | http://qspublic.s3.amazonaws.com https://qspublic.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ |
| FW OTA | http://vod.benq.com/tvservice_api/api/response.php https://d3bx1fc1zkxy8q.cloudfront.net https://donglefw.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ update.xml https://qotaapi.benq.com/api/v2/ https://vod.benq.com https://benqqota.firebaseio.com https://d1m7bten765ify.cloudfront.net |
| AMS | https://ams.benq.com/api/* https://www.googleapis.com https://api.dropboxapi.com |
| InstaQshare/InstaShare | http://h1.ee-share.com/ |
| BenQ Suggest | http://vod.benq.com/suggest/public/ |
| Easy Setting | https://smartdms.benq.com/ESApi/public http://relaysmartdms.benq.com:443 https://smartdms.benq.com.cn/ESApi/public http://relaysmartdms.benq.com.cn:443 |
| X-Sign | https://Relay.benq.com https://Apiservice.benq.com https://X-Sign.benq.com https://logapiservice.benq.com https://qspublic.s3.amazonaws.com https://xsignbdp-eu.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com https://vod.benq.com https://sa900-api.elasticbeanstalk.com https://api.openweathermap.org https://Relay.benq.com.cn https://Apiservice.benq.com.cn https://X-Sign.benq.com.cn https://logapiservice.benq.com.cn http://qspublic.s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn https://benqxsignbdp.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com https://benqxsignbdp.oss.aliyuncs.com https://vod.benq.com https://xsignbdp.s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn |
| DMS | https://dms.benq.com/ https://vod.benq.com/ http://staging2.benq.com https://dms-relay.benq.com https://cmota.s3.amazonaws.com/ https://dsdownload.benq.com apexd90h2t5wg-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com https://benq-dms-eu.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com |
| Qtouch | reg.wittydog.com.cn www.wittydog.com.cn |
| Blizz/TeamViewer | *.teamviewer.com *.blizz.com |
| Android Time Sync | time.android.com 2.android.pool.ntp.org |
| Broadcast | https://x-signbroadcast-relay.benq.com https://x-signbroadcast-api.benq.com https://X-Signbroadcast.benq.com https://qspublic.s3.amazonaws.com https://broadcastbdp-eu.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com https://vod.benq.com https://x-signbroadcast-relay.benq.com.cn https://x-signbroadcast-api.benq.com.cn https://X-Signbroadcast.benq.com.cn http://qspublic.s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn https://vod.benq.com https://broadcastbdp.s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn |
| InstaShare2 | https://vod.benq.com/ On your Windows firewall, allow access to the following application: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\InstaShare 2\BenQShare.exe |
| IAM | apitest.benq.com iam.benq.com |

Comment: For those who are not familiar with this device, by "updating apps", did you mean updating from Play Store? Or any other sources?

Comment: The default apps in the BenQ store - even though they are an Android device they don't have access to the normal Android app stores